# Knowledge Articles in English are not visible in the community for the users with other languages

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community, knowledge, articles, topics

We have the community with `Customer Service` template setup and we use Salesforce Knowledge base. 
Topics are set up in the `Content Management` - `Topic Management` and Articles are assigned in `Article Management`.

Topics are displayed with the standard Builder page `Topic Detail`. There is a standard component - `Articles With This Topic`.

When the logged-in user with **English** language access the page he is able to see the topics. Once he selects the topic he can see all articles assigned to that topic. This is fine.
[image]

But, when the user with any other language selects the same topic he does not see the articles and there is a message `No Article Found` instead.
[image]
If the user will paste the URL to the article directly, not the topic he would be able to see the article in default **English** language.
[image]
If there any way to fix this in the way that users with any language can see all related articles to the topic as **English** language user?

> NOTE: We do not want to translate articles but want to display them in
>   English for all user languages. BTW, Multiple languages are added to
>   Knowledge setting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any other solution than creating a custom component that retrieves articles by topic Id. 
Well, works fine.

Comment: I used "Trending Articles By Topic component" instead of "Articles with this Topic" and it worked for me.